# chat bot for telegram

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I create a bot for telegrams,
he should collect the id of everyone who wrote in the group chat for a certain time, but I can not extract the user's id from the messages, instead I get only the chat id

The question is how to me from messages sent to the chat to pull only the id of the user who sent the message.

to create a bot I use a python, please, give examples only on it.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['MyID'])
   def get_id(msg):
   bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "ID USER\n")
   bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, msg.chat.id)
```

Comment: You can't PM users before them send "/start" command

Comment: Just send them link like https://t.me/Sean_Bot?start=foo_bar